# VB.Net get app user settings from access database

Tags: .net, vb.net

Very much a beginner question, so many apologies.

I am new to VB.Net and I am trying to access an Access database table with user settings. I am working in Visual Studio Community edition 2015 and I am connecting to an instance of an application.

The code I am working with has a mix of the decompiled app and some add-ins which allow the external app to be configured to suit the user.

The types of configurable settings are: currency, logos, products, contacts management, accounts integration, etc.

I am connected to the database and I can add to tables, but I'm having difficulty seeing how to load the user settings to the external app from the settings data table.

I have started with something like this:

```
string sLookedUp = _DB.RunScalarQuery("SELECT * FROM SYSTEMSETTINGS WHERE NAME = '" + "SystemSettings" + "'");
```

But then how do I query the settings values and how do I code where the values are read to?

Comment: How many configurable settings are there? Do you need them to be actual columns in the database or could they all be stored as binary data in one column? I see that you have some plural items, such as "logos" - is you database normalised to have another table for the logos etc.?

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for replying, I really appreciate your help. There are access databases for different settings and content. Each database has one or many tables, so for example when I query the database SYSTEMSETTINGS above the name = "SystemSettings" refers to the system settings table within the system settings db. From there I would like to access the values for settings via a query on a known column header.

Comment: For example a column name may be KeyName which corresponds to the type of settings and KeyValue is the value for that setting. I am trying to load these settings to the app when the app is initialised by reading them from the database.